# Error trying to install argh-0.24.1 Python 3.2

Tags: python, ascii, pip, python-3.2

I'm trying to install [Argh-0.24.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argh) via pip on Mac OS X Mavericks but I'm getting a ascii decode error. Here is the traceback:

```
eos87@local ~> pip install argh        
Downloading/unpacking argh
  Downloading argh-0.24.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package argh
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/Users/eos87/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.2/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
        return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 55: ordinal not in range(128)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/Users/eos87/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.2/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode

    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 55: ordinal not in range(128)

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /Users/eos87/.virtualenvs/myenv/build/argh
Storing complete log in /Users/eos87/.pip/pip.log
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this would go better in [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)?

Comment: No, this is most likely a bug, and should be filed as an issue on the [GitHub project](https://github.com/neithere/argh). I have a strong suspicion the error is caused because [`README.rst` will be read as `ascii` during installation](https://github.com/neithere/argh/blob/master/setup.py#L53), and the author recently added non-ASCII characters to it. However, the code on github doesn't seem to be current (0.24.0), so I didn't investigate it further.

Comment: Yes, I think so. I'm going to create a new issue on the Github project. Thanks @LukasGraf

Comment: It is pretty weird, because I'm able to install it downloading the .tar.gz file, uncompressing it and doing 'python setup.py install', but using pip it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick search [this link](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=63490&p=471616) provided me with the first clue as to why this trouble is arising.

It seems your terminal is enforcing an incompatible locale upon your pip installation.

To fix this simply edit **~/.bash_profile**:

```
~: nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Then add these lines:

```
# Setting for the new UTF-8 terminal support in Lion
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

**NOTE:** if the file doesn't exist, simply create it.

Now close your terminal, open it again, and retry the installation.